# Changing the eventLimitText color in Fullcalendar with css or jquery on a dayClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have my fullcalendar in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbynbu4z/8/) and I'm coloring the selected day cells with a orange color when selected. So when selected the cell turns orange. I'm trying to figure out how I can change the 'eventLimitText' to white when the background is orange to create a better contrast? Currently the eventLimitText is grey and isn't meshing well with the orange when highlighted

Any help will be appreciated.

The biggest chanllenge is changing the color when the dayClick event occurs because fullcalendar uses some kind of table overlapping scheme, so the table that has the day cell isn't the same table that holds the eventLimitText.

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
   //defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
   defaultView: 'basicWeek',
   editable: false,
      height: 144,
      eventLimit: 1,
      eventLimitText: function (numEvents) {
       return numEvents;
      },
      eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
       $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $("td[data-date=" + cellInfo.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
      },
      dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
       $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $("td[data-date=" + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
      },
   events: [
    {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-11-18'
    },
    {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-11-18'
    },
        {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-11-15'
    },
    {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-11-15'
    }
   ]
  });
  
 });
```

```css
td.fc-more-cell {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.3em;

}
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, 
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tr{
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td div {
      display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
}

 input, textarea {
        max-width: none;
    }
    a.fc-day-grid-event:hover {
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    td {
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    #weekLeft, #weekRight {
        cursor: pointer !important;
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-top: 65px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid grey;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: grey;
    }
    #weekLeft:hover, #weekRight:hover {
        color: white;
        background: grey;
    }
    .fc-center > h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    /*td.fc-more-cell {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;

    }*/

    td.fc-more-cell {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.8em;
        vertical-align: middle
    }

    .fc-content-skeleton,
    table,
    tr {
        height: 100%;
    }
    a.fc-more:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
#stepsToListBtn:hover {
            cursor: default;
        }
        .glyphicon-remove {
            color: red;
        }
        .glyphicon-ok {
            color: green;
        }
        .nav-pills > li.active > a i {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0.25rem;
            border-radius: 0.5rem;
        }
        div.fc-scroller {
            overflow-y: hidden !important;
        }
        
        .disabled-date {
            background-color: grey;
            /*opacity: 0.7;*/
            color: #FFFFFF;
            cursor: default !important;
        }

        /*.seventy-two-hour-window {
            background-color: #FF5A5F !important;
            cursor: default !important;
        }

        .seventy-two-hour-color {
            color: white !important;
        }*/

        .fc-state-highlight {
            /*background-color: transparent !important;*/
            background-color: #FF5A5F !important;
            /*opacity: 1;*/
        }

        /*.spinner.default {
            padding-left: 27px;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }*/

        /*.spinner-offset {
            padding-left: 27px;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }*/

        .fc-more {
            /*color: #FF5A5F !important;*/
            color: grey !important;
        }

        .fc-highlight {
            background: none !important;
        }

        .nav-pills > li.active > a i {
            background: none;
        }
        .validCheck > li > a:hover, .validCheck > li > a:focus {
            background-color: transparent;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        div.arrow {
            left: 25% !important;
        }
        td {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .fc-unthemed td.fc-today {
            background: none;
        }
        div.fc-header-toolbar {
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        }

        #spaceMenu.nav-pills > li.active > a,
        #spaceMenu.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus,
        #spaceMenu.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
            background-color: transparent !important;
            color: black !important;
        }

        #spaceMenu.nav > li > a:focus,
        #spaceMenu.nav > li > a:hover {
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }

        #spaceMenu a {
            color: grey !important;
        }

        #spaceMenu a:hover {
            color: black !important;
        }
        .spinner > div {
            background-color: white !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/f7d7azcz/).

As you say, the problem here is finding the corresponding cell in the 2nd overlay table where the eventLimit text appears.  The overlay table cells don't have any handy date-based selectors, like the first table does, so it isn't obvious how to connect the 2 sets of cells.

One way you can do it is by finding the index of the clicked day from the first table, and finding the corresponding index in the overlay table where the eventLimit text appears.  You can then apply CSS to that corresponding overlay cell.

For example if you click on Tuesday, that is the 2nd (0-based) `<td>` in the set of day-of-the-week `<td>`s in the first table.  So the 2nd `<td>` in the corresponding `fc-content-skeleton` set (where eventLimit overlays are) should be the matching overlay cell.

It is not quite that simple though, as the eventLimit overlay table can include more `<td>`s than days of the week, depending on whether there are days with more than `eventLimit` events.  For those days, there is an additional `<td>` to hold the `eventLimitText`.  So our selection logic needs to ignore those cells.

AFAICT from your code, you want both `dayClick` and `eventLimitClick` to do exactly the same thing - highlight the clicked day.  Rather than duplicating code in each handler to do that, we can extract the code out to a function and call it from both handlers.

Here's a quick description of the JSFiddle code:

First, add a new CSS class for the `eventLimitText` on selected days.  I chose to use and apply your existing `fc-state-highlight` class to the 2nd table as well, but of course you could use a different class as suits:

```
.fc-more-cell.fc-state-highlight a.fc-more {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Now in your Fullcalendar code, call our function from each callback.  [Note that in `dayClick`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/):

> Within the callback function, 'this' is set to the  of the clicked day.

So it is easy to target the clicked cell just using `$(this).addClass()`, rather than using a complicated selector with `data-date`.

[Similarly for eventLimitClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimitClick/) we can use `cellInfo.dayEl`.

```
eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo, jsEvent) {
    dayClick(cellInfo.dayEl);
},
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    dayClick($(this));
},
```

And finally add our callback to handle either event:

```
function dayClick($target) {
    // First remove any previous highlighting
    $('td').removeClass('fc-state-highlight');

    // Highlight what was just clicked
    $target.addClass('fc-state-highlight');

    // Find which of the set of <td>s we just clicked 
    var index = $('.fc-bg td.fc-day').index($target);

    // Find the corresponding index in the fc-content-skeleton table,
    // ignoring the extra non-day <td>s
    $('div.fc-content-skeleton td')
    .not('.fc-limited')
    .eq(index)
    .addClass('fc-state-highlight');
}
```

Now our specific new CSS targets the clicked day's `eventLimitText`.